# Theme Customize API Panel Concept

Tags: theme-customizer, settings-api

I am assuming while writing this post that I have a clear understanding of the theme customizer API:

There are sections → Under which we have Panels → and under these panels we have Fields.

## I am unable to add Panel in the desired Location

Suppose I have created a section Named: newsletter→

```
$wp_customize->add_section( 'newsletter', array(
        'title'       => __( 'Newsletter', 'twentytwelve' ),
        'priority'    => 41,
    ) );
```

And under this section, there are many fields. Let me show one example →

```
 $fields[] = array(
        'type'     => 'text',
        'settings' => 'twentytwelve_mailchimp_key',
        'label'    => __( 'MailChimp API Key', 'my_textdomain' ),
        'section'  => 'newsletter',
        'default'  => esc_attr__( 'Please enter your key', 'my_textdomain' ),
        'priority' => 10,
    );
```

As mentioned above there are many such fields(say there are 12 such fields).

## QUESTION →

As we put fields under a section by using this `'section'  => 'newsletter',`
How can we put a field under panel also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields always go in sections. *Sections* go in panels.

```
$wp_customize->add_panel( 'newsletter_panel', array(
    'title'    => __( 'Newsletter', 'twentytwelve' ),
    'priority' => 41,
) );

$wp_customize->add_section( 'newsletter', array(
    'title'    => __( 'Newsletter', 'twentytwelve' ),
    'priority' => 41,
    'panel'    => 'newsletter_panel'
) );
```

That will put a "Newsletter" section inside a "Newsletter" panel. All the fields should still be attached to the *section*.

Comment: Ok. Thanks so this is the key → `'panel'    => 'newsletter_panel'` Its just like setting submenus in the section. I hope one section can have more than one panel right? If my understanding is correct and say there are two panels then how can we assign few fields to one panel and the remaining fields to other panels. the section is the same "newsletter"

Comment: You're getting them backwards. You add panels, then sections go inside panels, then fields go inside sections.

Comment: Thanks! I got it Now. Panels → settings → fields: That's the flow.